# What exactly is not iterable here, and how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

This kind of questions has been asked a lot here, but I still don't know why it happens here. The error massage is:

> TypeError: 'P' object is not iterable

and is invoked by `for p in self.parents:` from `__str__`

Why `P` isn't iterable?

```
class P:
    limit = 8

    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0,p=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.parents = p

    def __str__(self):
        s = ''
        for p in self.parents:
            s += '({},{}->)'.format(p.x,p.y)
        s += '({},{}->)'.format(self.x,self.y)
        return s + '\n'

    def next_move(self):
        def valid(x):
            return x >= 0 and x < P.limit

        x,y = self.x,self.y
        a = [-1,1]
        b = [-2,2]
        ls = [(x+i, y+j) for i in a for j in b if valid(x+i) and valid(y+j)]
        ls +=[(x+i, y+j) for i in b for j in a if valid(x+i) and valid(y+j)]
        to_return = []
        for i in range(len(ls)):
            to_return += P(ls[i][0],ls[i][1],self)
        return to_return 


p = P()
print (p.next_move())
```

**EDIT:**
My issue here is not how to remove the error (using `append`) but how to use `next_move()` to create a list of new `P` that are a horse-move (Chess) away from the parent, and also append said parent to the `parents` attribute in the new object. The answers you gave me help avoid the error, but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Why should it be iterable? Google what makes something an iterable. `P().parents` should probably be a sequence of `P` objects rather than a single `P` instance.

Comment: `P(ls[i][0],ls[i][1],self)`: you pass `self` as the `parents` argument which is iterated in the `__str__` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

Firstly, You are trying to add a `P` instance to a list via `+=`. But `+=` for lists roughly corresponds to `extend` and takes an iterable:

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
    to_return += [P(...)]
    # OR
    # to_return.append(P(...))
```

Secondly, when you call the constructor with `P(ls[i][0], ls[i][1], self)`, you are passing `self` as the `p` parameter which should be iterable itself. You might want to use `P(ls[i][0], ls[i][1], [self])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually getting this error at the following line:

```
to_return += P(ls[i][0],ls[i][1],self)
```

This is because you should be appending to `to_return` like this

```
to_return.append(P(ls[i][0],ls[i][1],self))
```

or, if you have any particular reasons to do so, like this:

```
to_return += [P(ls[i][0],ls[i][1],self)]
```

In addition, that `self` you passed as argument is not iterable either. *Then* you would have the problem in `__str__`, if it was to be called.

```
to_return.append(P(ls[i][0], ls[i][1], [self]))
```

Finally, I believe you meant `__repr__` instead of `__str__`, so that you print:

```
[(0,0->)(1,2->)
, (0,0->)(2,1->)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class P:
    limit = 8

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, p=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.parents = p

    def __str__(self):
        s = ''
        for p in self.parents:
            s += '({},{}->)'.format(p.x, p.y)
        s += '({},{}->)'.format(self.x, self.y)
        return s + '\n'

    def next_move(self):
        def valid(x):
            return 0 <= x < P.limit

        x, y = self.x, self.y
        a = [-1, 1]
        b = [-2, 2]
        ls = [(x + i, y + j) for i in a for j in b if valid(x + i) and valid(y + j)]
        ls += [(x + i, y + j) for i in b for j in a if valid(x + i) and valid(y + j)]
        to_return = []
        for i in range(len(ls)):
            to_return.append(P(ls[i][0], ls[i][1], self))
        return to_return


p = P()
print(p.next_move())
```

See changes in **Line 27**

Because ***to_return*** is a **list**, so we can't use **+** operator. We can use **append function** for **list**.